# Codeigniter URI routing with for multiple methods

Tags: codeigniter-2

I am working on codeigniter. Controller name is "project" and 4 functions are there.."get_city_data", "get_store_data", "get_currency", "get_description".

Parameters I am passing in above 2 functions are - get_city_data($state, $city), get_place_data($state, $city, $store).

So on browser to render these functions I am using the urls respectively as-

http://localhost/project/get_city_data/state1/city1

I want to change the urls like 
http://localhost/state1/city1

In routes.php if I define a route like this
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'project/get_city_data/$1/$2' then it reflects for all other functions as well but I want to change urls for these 2 functions only.

Also I do not want to use _remap function as it doesn't go well with my needs.

Can anybody help me in this? 
ThankYou

Comment: Urls now are like
1. http://localhost/project/get_city_data/state1/city1
2. http://localhost/project/get_place_data/state1/city1/store1

I want urls to be like
1. http://localhost/state1/city1
2. http://localhost/state1/city1/store1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved using regex.

In routes.php i wrote

```
$url_source = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(!(preg_match('%^/project/get_description\?state=[a-zA-Z_-]*%', $url_source) || preg_match('%^/project/get_currency\?state=[a-zA-Z_-]*%', $url_source))){

        if(!preg_match('%^\/[a-zA-Z_-]+\/[a-zA-Z_-]+\/[a-zA-Z_-]+$%', $url_source)){
                $route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'project/get_city_data/$1/$2';
        }else{
                $route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'project/get_store_data/$1/$2/$3';
        }
}
```

This way I was able to route for particular functions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check in the database at first, then determine the routes required. Here is my answer for your requirement.

In your **routes.php**, try this code:

```
require_once( BASEPATH . 'database/DB' . EXT );

$url_source = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
$arr_url = explode("/", $url_source);

$state_name = $arr_url[3];
$city_name  = $arr_url[4];
$store_name = $arr_url[4];

$db = & DB();

//Let say grab 3 columns to be check
$db->select('state_name, city_name, store_name');


if(!empty($state_name)):
    $db->where('state_name', $state_name);
endif;

if(!empty($city_name)):
    $db->where('city_name', $city_name);
endif;

if(!empty($store_name)):
    $db->where('store_name', $store_name);
endif;

$query = $db->get('table', 1);
$obj = $query->row();
if ($obj):
    $route["$obj->state_name/$obj->city_name/$obj->store_name"] = "project/get_city_data/$state_name/$city_name/$store_name";
endif;
```

You can try by this url to test:

```
http://localhost/state_name/city_name/store_name
```

Comment: I already tried this. I am fetching the payload using another function which doesn't give data if I make these changes in route.php

Comment: Simply the question is can we make the url with only arguments passed in the function without giving any controller or function name by matching the function name in regex or something like django allows.